# timestamp and enterprise architect (sparx)

Tags: oracle, timestamp, enterprise-architect

Im trying to use Enterprise Architect to model Oracle database. Everything is going fine, but I have one problem. I dont know how to set TIMESTAMP as a type of the column.

anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Menu Settings -> Database Datatypes

Select "Oracle" as Product Name and add "TIMESTAMP" as Datatype.